# 403 Forbidden Error with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I'm suddenly seeing a 403 Forbidden error when I visit one of my client's WordPress sites. No one at the company has even logged in recently, so this came rather suddenly. The site is down and I'm not allowed to access the wp-admin.

I have already disabled all plugins via FTP, so it's not that.

Everyone is having the same issue, so it's not my IP.

I also ruled out a theme specific issue since changing the theme name in FTP didn't lead anywhere.

There is a .htaccess file, which it says was created in 2013, but it's got a 644 permission so I'm not sure what the problem might be. I temporarily removed the file and that didn't fix the problem, either. Here is the code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.wpwordpress.com/how-to-solve-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/ this might help. Also check file permissions.

Comment: Check the apache error logs for that domain.  It may say why it is returning a 403 error.